# up-to-date PyGTK tutorial

Tags: pygtk

The [official tutorial](http://pygtk.org/tutorial.html) hasn't been updated in years. Is there a more up-to-date one elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been working on my own [PyGTK documentation website](http://www.learngtk.org/) for a little bit now. The tutorial is mostly complete except for some sections which I'm aiming to complete in the next week or so.

Comment: I am using your tutorial to learn PYGTK. However, I've run into a bump. Please Help.Question : [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807917/typeerror-object-of-type-gtkspinner-does-not-have-property-num-steps)

Answer (score 2):

Check the new [GNOME Developer Center](http://developer.gnome.org/), especially the new 10-minute tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know that PyGTK is getting quite old, and that you should actually use [PyGObject.](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject).
Never the less, some linux distribution like RHEL will be outhere fore quite a while, so if you develop software that runs there, PyGTK is not a bad choice.

The above mentioned official tutorial is quite overwhelming for a new comer in my opinion. I use this tutorial as a reference to see how things are done, together with the official [PyGTK reference.](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/)
That said, I can also recommend some other tutorials:

1. The comprehensive [PyGTK tutorial by Andrew Steele](http://learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/) - like the official one, it is BIG. And the stuff you create following the tutorial is mini "useless" applications, which demonstrate each widget.
2. The [PyGTK tutorial by zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/) takes a more gradual approach with steps building on each other to create more complicated windows and menus etc, and by that unfolding more and more GTK widgets and their usage.
3. And finally, another [tutorial for PyGTK](http://oz123.github.com/writings/2013-01-03-A%20Complete%20PyGTK%20CD%20Ripper%20Tutorial/) (Full disclosure: the author of this post, is also the author of this PyGTK tutorial), which does not cover the whole set of widget - however, it covers enough to teach you how to walk by your own through PyGTK. It is different from other tutorials in its approach. There is not so much theory (Although, I would not skip reading it in the first part of the official PyGTK tutorial), and there are no mini applications. Instead, this PyGTK tutorial, takes an existing GTK application (written in C) and demonstrates how one can rewrite it in Python. In the end of the current 6 parts, the GUI is complete and functional. I realize that some might not like the very verbal and gradual approach, but that is OK.

Comment: +1 for #3, I've seen enough widget libraries by this point, showing application structure is *very* helpful.

Comment: @msw, thanks! sometimes FOSS documentation is quite lacking in this direction ... That was my humble contribution, and I still need to write part 7-N? ...