# TypeError :object of type 'GtkSpinner' does not have property 'num-steps'

Tags: python, spinner, pygtk

I am learning about Spinners in PyGtk. I executed this program :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class Spinner:
    def __init__(self):
        window=gtk.Window()
        window.set_default_size(200,200)

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 5)
        hbox = gtk.HBox(True, 5)

        self.spinner = gtk.Spinner()
        self.spinner.set_property("num-steps", 10)

        button_start = gtk.Button("Start")
        button_stop = gtk.Button("Stop")

        window.connect("destroy", lambda q : gtk.main_quit())
        button_start.connect("clicked", self.start_animation)
        button_stop.connect("clicked", self.stop_animation)

        window.add(vbox)
        vbox.pack_start(self.spinner,True,True,0)
        vbox.pack_end(hbox, False, False, 0)
        hbox.pack_start(button_start)
        hbox.pack_start(button_stop)

        window.show_all()

    def start_animation(self, widget):
        self.spinner.start()

    def stop_animation(self, widget):
        self.spinner.stop()

Spinner()
gtk.main()
```

Shell threw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spinner.py", line 37, in <module>
    Spinner()
  File "spinner.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.spinner.set_property("num-steps", 10)
TypeError: object of type `GtkSpinner' does not have property `num-steps'
```

It throws a similar error in the case of `cycle-duration` property of Spinner. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I take it [this](http://learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/spinner.html) is the tutorial you're following? It certainly seems like you're doing the right thing (though I'm not personally familiar with this). The [docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkspinner.html) don't seem to help much either...

Comment: @mhlester Actually it's [this one by Andrew Steele](http://www.learngtk.org/pygtk-tutorial/packages/pygtktutorial.pdf). But yes, it's the same program.

Comment: Are you posting the actual file and real, unmodified output you are working with? The line `self.spinner.set_property("cycle-duration", 1000)` mentioned in the traceback isn't in the file you posted and isn't consistent with the error you report.

Comment: oh yea..I wanted to post a question for `num-steps` originally. But then added the traceback for `cycle-duration` mistakenly as it was the first thing I saw on my screen.Fixing it.

Comment: @MikeGraham Done! However, as you may have observed shell throws a similar error in case of `cycle-duration`.

Comment: Someone please answer/help!